# Discrepancy between reactive and non-reactive Quarkus JAX-RS endpoints wrt URL decoding of PathParam

Tags: quarkus, resteasy, quarkus-reactive, path-parameter

After migrating an existing webapp from DropWizard to latest Quarkus (3.1, resteasy-reactive), things are working well except for some edge cases we have found.
One in particular looks like possible bug: handling of URL path parameters wrt decoding of percent-encoded entities. We noticed that end point like:

```
@ApplicationScoped
@Path("/path")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public class PathResource
{
    @GET
    @Path("/list/{primaryKey: .+}")
    public String pathAsList(@PathParam("primaryKey") List<PathSegment> path)
    {
    }
```

will, given URL like:

```
http://localhost:8081/path/list/ab%2Fcd/ef%2Fgh
```

produce different `List` when run using "quarkus-resteasy" and "quarkus-resteasy-reactive":

- With blocking (quarkus-resteasy) we get `List` of 2 segments: "ab/cd" and "ef/gh"
- With reactive we get `List` of 4 segments: "ab", "cd", "ef" and "gh"

of these former is, I think, correct; and is what DropWizard (Jersey) also does.

I will file an issue against Quarkus but was hoping to see if anyone knew more about this discrepancy, possibly having a work-around or something.

Comment: This looks like a bug and has since been reported at: https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues/34586

Comment: Correct, thank you @geoand that is indeed the filed bug.